# onMouse over function doesn't work otherwise it does

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function but if I use it, it doesn't work. If I use the same code without the function on my html it does work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jon(str) {
    id = 'j'+str;
    getElementById(id).setAttribute('class', '');
}
function jover(str) {
    id = 'j'+str;
    getElementById(id).setAttribute('class', 'hide');
}
</script>

<form id="lijst" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return formOK();">
    <table>
        <tr onMouseOver="getElementById('jtitle').setAttribute('class', '');" onMouseOut="getElementById('jtitle').setAttribute('class', 'hide');">
            <th>* Title</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
            <td id="jtitle" class="hide">Vul een film of serie titel in.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onMouseOver="jon('type');" onMouseOut="jover('type');">
            <th>* Type</th>
            <td><select name="type"><option value="film">Film</option><option value="serie">Serie</option></select></td>
            <td id="jtype" class="hide"></td>
        </tr>
```

The title does work, but the type doesn't work.
The console says the getElementById() isn't defined. I tried to put `var id = ''` for the functions but that doesn't work.

So how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the prefix `document.`:

```
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute(...);
```

The `getElementById` method is defined on the `document` object. In order to call a method on any object you need to use the object on which it is defined, followed by a dot `.` and the method name. For example:

```
document.getElementById()
   |    ^       |
   |            |
   |            |
[object]    [method]
```

The only exception is for the `window` object, where that is not required when you define a function or variable on it; you can use it as if it were free-standing. But in actuality all *global* variables in particular are on the window object. This can be caused by accidentally omitting the `var` keyword when creating a variable. For example:

```
x = 5;
```

Assume that a variable `x` has not been previously defined. Since `x` was *not* created with the `var` keyword, it's put on the `window` object. We can check it in the console:

```
>> window.x;

 : 5
```

This can lead to sticky situations in that it can conflict with another `x` variable declared in an outer scope. That's why it's always important to define with `var`. There shouldn't be a reason not to.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot all about the document, and because it did work in the html, i didn't that that i was forgot something as that.

Comment: Really use full!  Specially that object.method thing ^^